# If the symbol '$f^{-1}$' shows up as an assumption, can I automatically assert that $f$ is a function?

Tags: calculus, definition, inverse-function, convention

In Chapter 12 of Spivak's *Calculus*, the definition of the **inverse** of function $f$ is provided as:

> For any function $f$, the inverse of $f$, denoted by $f^{-1}$, is the set of all pairs $(a,b)$ for which the pair $(b,a)$ is in $f$

Given the above definition, is it fair for me to say that if the symbol '$f^{-1}$' shows up as an assumption, I can automatically assert that $f$ is a function?

The context for this question comes from a Spivak-provided theorem:

> If $f^{-1}$ is a function, then $f$ is one-to-one.

Spivak's proof reads:

> Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is a function. $\color{red}{\text{If } f(b)=f(c)}$, then $f$ contains the pairs $(b,f(b))$ and $(c,f(c))=(c,f(b))$, so $(f(b),b)$ and $(f(b),c)$ are in $f^{-1}$. Since $f^{-1}$ is a function, this implies that $b=c$. Thus $f$ is one-to-one.

I have highlighted in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ where my confusion lays. As far as I know, the syntax '$f(x)$' is only to be used if we know that $f$ is a function...so there must be an implicit understanding that $f$ is a function.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, the definition in the second paragraph does not imply that $f^{-1}$ is a function. Take $f =1$ for $x \in [0,1]$ for example, then $f^{-1}$ is the **relation** $\{ (1,x) \}_{x \in [0,1]}$ which is definitely not a function.

Comment: @copper.hat Maybe I am misunderstanding you...but I do not think you are responding to the correct question

Comment: You are correct, I misread. Yes, $f$ would be a function in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right in the first clause in the definition: "For any function $f$..."

That means he is only defining $f^{-1}$ on functions.  The definition he then gives yields a relations that is itself a function if and only if the original function was injective.

Note:  There's no reason you can't define the inverse of a generic relation in the same way and the same definition would work even if $f$ wasn't a function.  But since he includes that clause, he's restricting the definition of the symbol $f^{-1}$ to cases where $f$ is a function

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, Spivak certainly means that $f$ is a function. That said, this result can be extended to relations as follows.
Let us say that a relation $\tau: E \to F$ is *injective* if, for every $u,v \in E$, $\tau(u) \cap \tau(v) \not= \emptyset$ implies $u = v$. Then the following result holds:

> A relation is injective if and only if its inverse is a partial function.

Comment: Could you please clarify the definition of the injective relation? Why is "$\tau(u) \cap \tau(v)=\emptyset$" conceptually similar to "$f(a)=f(b)$"

Comment: Ooops, there was a typo. It should be $\tau(u) \not= \tau(v)$. Thank you very much for your comment.